# Layout issue of "question feed" text overlapping when page contains small amount of data

Tags: bug, questions, design, rss

There is a layout issue when page contains posts in the list at the time. "*recently active yii2-extension questions feed*" text overlapping to right side panel/bar:

[image: SCREENSHOT-1]

**Another snap:**

[image: SCREENSHOT-2]

Comment: I reported this bug when the new-nav first came out. It's been fixed twice but someone keeps putting `white-space: nowrap` back in the code.

Comment: when it has few post at that time this occur. but when many post available so it's fine.

Comment: Well, there is no real need for `white-space: nowrap` to be there. One or more of the designers thinks that it should all be on one line.

Comment: **recently active yii2-extension questions feed**  should be change to a bit left side to prevent  from overlapping.

Comment: @CoolGuy: *Ovals.